# MySQL strips leading zeros when converting hex to binary

Tags: mysql, binary

`SELECT CONV('01ae0ac8', 16,2)` removes leading **0's** from the binary output. I need these **0's** for to perform checks.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thank you

Comment: What you can do is append a non-zero character , let's say 'a' before the string before `CONV`
Post reconverting it back to base16, remove the 'a' from the beginning.

Comment: Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can append a non-zero **fixed** character, to the beginning of your input string, before converting it from base-16 to base-2.
For eg:

```
SELECT CONV(CONCAT('a','01ae0ac8'), 16,2)
```

This shall give you the following output:

```
101000000001101011100000101011001000
```

Now, while reconverting it back to base-16 for checksum, do the following:

```
SELECT LCASE(SUBSTRING(CONV('101000000001101011100000101011001000', 2,16),2))
```

This shall give you the following output:

```
01ae0ac8
```

Note:

1. [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function is used to append 'a' to beginning.
2. [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function is used to remove first character ('a') from the re-converted base-16 string.
3. [LCASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lcase) function is used to convert it into lowercase, as the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Madhur, you put me on the right track.

I did the following and it seems to be working:

```
SELECT CONV(CONCAT('1','01ae0ac8'), 16,2) //I changed your a to 1
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONV('101000000001101011100000101011001000', 2,16),2,1) // Checking to see if the 1 is in the first position.
```

Thank you for your prompt reply.
Kind Regards